# How do I install Gentoo Linux alongside existing Ubuntu (dual boot)?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, dual-boot, gentoo

I have Ubuntu as the only operating system installed on my laptop and want to make dual boot with Gentoo. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to

- resize a partition (unless you have free space), you can do it easily with gparted
- install gentoo on the free space
- install grub with os-prober (Or you can insert manually the ubuntu partition you can insert the "Ubuntu" entry manually http://ubuntuguide.net/manually-addingremoving-entries-to-grub-2-menu)